# link around div in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, hyperlink

I have a parent div and few other divs nested in it containing text.
what I want to do is to **change the background color of my parent div on hover and redirect to another page on click**

so i did

```
<a href="">
  <div class="parentDiv">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>user</div>
  </div>
</a>

.parentDiv:hover{background-color:#72c1bf;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;}
```

and it actually works in IE8 and firefox but in chrome I have underlined all the single textes inside the two child divs. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because text-decorations are on `<a>` tag, you need to set `text-decoration: none;` for the `<a>` tags too.

But, according to the html standard, a `<a>` tag, wich is an inline element, should not contain any block elements, such as `<div>`'s, see [html specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)

Comment: according to specifications..how could i do this properly then?=)

Comment: by putting you <a> inside the divs, like `<div><a href="#">hello</a></div>`

Comment: In HTML 5 it is a block element (or maybe inline-block). It might help in earlier browsers to set `display: block` on the `a` tag, although that didn't fix the underline issue in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Try `a:hover{text-decoration:none}` testing it in ie9 and chrome with your original code doesn't work eben with the !important attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try this perhaps:

```
<a href="" class="link">
  <div class="parentDiv">
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>user</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

And CSS:

```
a.link{display:block; text-decoration:none}
.parentDiv:hover{background-color:#72c1bf;cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a single

```
<a>
```

tag is a problem(like it was for me). Use this:

```
<a href='#' style='text-decoration:none;' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `text-decoration: none` to the `a` tag made it go away, but I'm not sure if Chrome is right or wrong, here. Using an `a` tag as a block element like that works, but I'm not sure how legal it is prior to HTML 5. Also, I had to add `color: black`, otherwise the text was also blue or purple (visited or unvisited link color).